# Language sync in Sitecore with Unicorn

Tags: unicorn, language-fallback

I've installed sitecore 9 and I am using Unicorn to sync my developer items.

Do I create all my languages on my local machine an add the "`/sitecore/system/Languages`" to my Unicorn synchronization, so that I configure the languages only once like language fallback?

Is that the right approach or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can. I normally do.

Just be aware of this; I've been in one situation in the past where additional languages were added on a higher environment - which would mess things up.

But go ahead and do it, just make sure this is coordinated and known.

Comment: I've added my Languages to my unicorn sync at that seems to work fine so far.